# Displaying data from two tables in java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

i want to display messages with the sender name. The outer while loop is working fine but there is some problem in the inner while loop. I have tried a lot to figure out but got no result. Can anyone help me? I'll very thankful.

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Messages extends Login {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    boolean isLoggedin = login();

    String msg = "";
    String senName = "";

    if(isLoggedin) {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false", "root", "");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM chat");
        ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");
        while(rs.next()) {
            int dbRecID = rs.getInt("reciever_id");
            if(dbRecID == user_id) {
                msg = rs.getString("message");
                int dbSenID = rs.getInt("sender_id");
                while(rs1.next()) {
                    int senID = rs1.getInt("id");
                    if(senID == dbSenID) {
                        senName = rs1.getString("name");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(senName+" sent you a message: "+msg);
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Login Unsuccessful");
    }
}
}
```

**Output**

```
Ali Ahmed sent you a message: How are you?
Ali Ahmed sent you a message: Hi!
```

**Required Output**

```
Ali Ahmed sent you a message: How are you?
Hamza sent you a message: Hi!
```

Comment: please explain why you think that the output should be like "Required Output"

Comment: Because in the database there are two messages. One sent by Ali Ahmed and the other one by Hamza. The program is printing all the messages perfectly but it is not updating the sender name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the two nested `while` loops.

The query `ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");` is executed just once.

The first time you loop on `while(rs.next())` you will fetch the whole content of `rs1` to check if the sender id is the right one.

Then on the second iteration on `while(rs.next())` because `rs1` has been already fetched  `while(rs1.next())` wil return `false`.

In order to have your code working you should move the execution of the second query to get something like this:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    ...
    ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");
    while(rs1.next()) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

> But I think that it would be a better solution to make just one SQL
>   request joining the datas of the two tables and including the where
>   condition.

Comment: Hi Nirekin, Thank you so much for your help! This method worked for me. Thanks again! :)